# How to convert a large XML file with data in single line format to multipleline xml file using shell script

Tags: xml, powershell, shell

I have a shell script in place which is using 'SED' command to break single line xml to multiple line xml data. but for files larger than 2GB- SED command is failing.

sed 's/></>\n</g' is what we are using.

Comment: This is called _pretty printing_ A common way is to read the document as XML and [use XmlTextWriter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/format-xml/) to save it in nice a format.

Comment: Why did you tag `PowerShell`? are you looking for a PowerShell/.Net solution instead?

Answer (score 1):

For large documents a *streaming* approach using the .NET classes [`XmlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-6.0) and [`XmlTextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter?view=net-6.0) can be used. This avoids loading the whole document into memory and will also be faster because a DOM doesn't have to be created.

```sh
$inputPath  = 'input.xml'
$outputPath = 'output.xml'

$reader = $writer = $null

try {
    # Open the input file
    $reader = [Xml.XmlReader]::Create(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $inputPath ))

    # Create or overwrite the output file
    $null = New-Item $outputPath -ItemType File -Force
    $writer = [Xml.XmlTextWriter]::new(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $outputPath ), [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

    # This produces a multiline, indented output document
    $writer.Formatting = [Xml.Formatting]::Indented

    # This copies all elements from the input to the output document,
    # while applying the formatting.    
    $writer.WriteNode( $reader, $false )
}
finally {
    # Close the input and output files
    if( $writer ) { $writer.Dispose() }
    if( $reader ) { $reader.Dispose() }
}
```

**Example Input:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mydoc><foo><bar a="4" b="16">baz</bar></foo><test x="23" y="42"/></mydoc>
```

**Example Output:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mydoc>
  <foo>
    <bar a="4" b="16">baz</bar>
  </foo>
  <test x="23" y="42" />
</mydoc>
```

**Notes:**

- `Convert-Path` is used to make absolute paths from PowerShell paths, compatible with .NET API, which uses a different *current directory* variable. As `Convert-Path` expects an existing file, we use `New-Item` to create the output file beforehand.
- Make sure to dispose the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` instances so the files get closed and any data still in the buffer gets written out.